# Countable set (discrete) function continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, real-numbers

Suppose $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ is countable. Then, there exists a bijective $f: A \to \mathbb{N}$. Is this $f$ continuous since all points in the range are isolated points?

That is, I want to prove that countable subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ are disconnected. To do so, I want to show that $A$ is disconnected, since $f$ is continuous and continuous functions take connected sets to connected sets, and clearly $\mathbb{N}$ is not connected, for some disjoin $U,V$, $U \cup V = \mathbb{N}$, so that $f^{-1}(U) \cap f^{-1}(V) = A$.

Is $f$ continuous? Is this proof valid if so?

Answer (score 2):

It is not true that $f$ is continuous. For example, if $A=\mathbb Q$, then there are no isolated points in $A$.

It is true that $f^{-1}$ is continuous.

Now, being a discrete topology is not the same as being disconnected. The discrete topology is often called "totally disconnected," which is much stronger than disconnected.

The way to prove any countable set is disconnected is to pick two points $a<b\in A$ and show there must be a real number $x\notin A$ such that $a<x<b$. Then $(-\infty,x)\cap A$ and $(x,\infty)\cap A$ partition $A$ into two open sets.

So, for this proof, you only need that $A$ has a smaller cardinality than $\mathbb R$ and that $A$ has at least two elements.

Note that this is a strong disconnection, in that any two distinct $a,b\in A$ can be put into different components. It still isn't a total disconnection.

Comment: Is it alright that I have proved the following: For each $a \in A$, there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that $B_\epsilon (a) \cap A = \{a\}$. If not, the $B_\epsilon (a)$ would contain infinitely many points of $A$, so that $B_\epsilon (a) = A$. Thus, such an $\epsilon$ exists. Now, let $N \in \mathbb{N}$, $a_N < a_{N+1}$ Then, $U= (-\infty,a_N] \cap A$ and $V = [a_{N+1}, \infty) \cap A$ will do the trick, by the choice of $\epsilon$. That is to say, $a_N$ and $a_{N+1}$ are at least $\epsilon$ away and thus the sets are separated.

Comment: I believe this is the same this, if your $x$ is in this epsilon ball.

Comment: @AnthonyPeter You can't have proved that for $A=\mathbb Q$. Having infinitely many points of $A$ does not mean having all of $A$, just as having infinitely many elements of $\mathbb N$ doeasn't mean you have all of $\mathbb N$.

Comment: Then isn't the existence of such an $x$ trivial? Can I not say, let $x \in A^{c}$, and thus the two sets are separated and equal $A$?

Comment: No. If $A=[0,1]\cap\mathbb Q$, and you choose $x=2$, then $(x,+\infty)\cap A=\emptyset$. @AnthonyPeter I need $a\in(-\infty,x)$ and $b\in(x,+\infty)$ to ensure the two open subsets of $A$ are non-empty.

Comment: okay, well clearly, for two elements of $d(a, b) > \epsilon$ for some $\epsilon$. Thus, there exists an element in R\A between these two elements, since R is dense in itself. Is this okay?

Comment: No. Where are you using that $A$ is countable? You don't need an $\epsilon$ here.